# Trying to do a search query via a GET request in Node.js and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

I have the following function in my REST API using Node.js and MongoDB that I am building to do a search:

```
exports.searchPhone = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const phoneNumber = req.query.phone;
        const locations = await Location.find({
            phone: phoneNumber 
        });
        res.json(locations);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
};
```

I am not getting any errors in my response, but I am not getting any results either, despite the fact that I am passing a phone number that I know exists in my database.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whether `console.log(locations)` is printing??? Also check your `phoneNumber` is printing proper;y

Comment: Also can try to add a console in your catch `console.log(err)`

Comment: @Subburaj Thanks very much for your comment.  I think I see my issue here.  My phone number in MongoDB is stored as a String value as"+123456789", so when I pass my phone parameter in the request, I am also sending it in as "+123456789".  However, when I do console.log(phoneNumber), my output to the console is:  123456789 (i.e. no + sign).  How do I correct this?

Comment: @syedfa You can just concat the string `phoneNumber = "+" + phoneNumber` and pass it in query

Comment: @Subburaj Thanks again.  My phoneNumber property is having a space between the + and the number (i.e. + 123456789).

Comment: @syedfa where in DB?? or in the query??

Comment: @Subburaj in the query.

Comment: @syedfa You can use `trim` function to get solved this. use can use as follows  `phoneNumber = "+" + phoneNumber.trim()`

Comment: @Subburaj That worked!  Can you post your comments into an answer, and I'll approve?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @syedfa Glad to help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the query like below:

```
phoneNumber = "+" + phoneNumber.trim()
```